Should we call an API inside useEffect in React?
I heard that it is not a good practice to call an api inside useEffect, also thats why in dev mode useEffect runs twice.I am not sure about it, but if not useEffect, then what else?
Need fellow devs suggestions on it.Thank you

Yes, this is correct. but you can still use useEffect I which is not a big issue.
The perfect fix is to use React Query.

Do you use StrictMode? This might be responsible that things run twice. Depending on your use case, fetching data in useEffect is fine. As @ShahVipul mentioned, React Query is a possible solution to manage server state - but again, it depends (I wouldn't call it the perfect fix).

Where did you hear that this isn't a good practice? It's literally what useEffect is for, issuing side-effects like fetching data. Your question is too subjective or too broad and needs more focus. Is there some specific issue you have with calling some APIs in a useEffect hook callback?

No I didnt face any issues but it is a question I got asked few times in interviews, that's why I searched and is asking for the suggestions.

It's okay to use useEffect for simple api calls with simples states.
However, you can take a look at React Query. It's better as it handle loading, errors, caching, and render only when necessary.
Example GET :
// fetch data using react query
function Example() {
  const { isPending, error, data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['repoData'], // cache key
    queryFn: () =>
      fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/TanStack/query').then((res) =>
        res.json(),
      ),
  })

  if (isPending) return 'Loading...'

  if (error) return 'An error has occurred: ' + error.message

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <p>{data.description}</p>
      <strong> {data.subscribers_count}</strong>{' '}
      <strong>✨ {data.stargazers_count}</strong>{' '}
      <strong> {data.forks_count}</strong>
    </div>
  )
}


Calling an api in useEffect is okay as long as your component is not re-rendering Unnecessarily. Just make the dependency array empty or add the states/variables/props on which payload is changing.

It's okay to send an HTTP request in useEffect(), but sometimes you might not need an effect:

If this logic is caused by a particular interaction, keep it in the event handler. If it’s caused by the user seeing the component on the screen, keep it in the Effect.

See Sending a POST request 

Effects let you synchronize a component with some external system (third-party API, network, etc).

See What are Effects and how are they different from events?

It is absolutely acceptable to utilize useEffect for the purpose you mentioned. While there is a concern for issues such as infinite loops, decreased performance efficiency, etc, these issues can be avoided through proper organization.
Regarding the running of useEffect being twice, this occurs in dev mode to aid in searching for any potential issues.
If you're keen on looking for alternatives, you can consider event handlers or perhaps context API's. Although there are still more options out there to consider.
